# Cannot create directory: No space left on device

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, tar, inode

I have a `.tar` file of 13 GB. When I am trying to extract it on a drive it is showing me an error after completing of 3 or 4 GB extract.

Error is:

```
Cannot create directory: No space left on device
```

but there have still 21 GB free space.

Here is the image of the inode usage:

[image]

I need to to extract that `tar` file, how can i do this?

Comment: Whats the output of `df -h`?

Comment: /dev/sda6        81G   61G   20G  76% /media/shuvo/E
 It is the output  thanks :)

Comment: Is the archive a compressed one?

Comment: yes..actually it is an wikipedia static dump ...it was as .tar.7z then i have extract it i got .tar file it is also compressed :)

Comment: I don't see your `/home` directory there, and everything else is 20MB or less. `/dev/sda6` has `20M` free not `20G` free. How much RAM do you have and what is the situation of this system?

Comment: 20M that is Inode free not space...there have 20GB of free space still now ...and my ram is 4GB and os is 14.04

Comment: So the `tar` file contains compressed files now?

Comment: yes...BTW how can i check compressed file total size that has in that tar file by using command??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `tar` archive now that contains compressed files, and while unarchiving them all at once you are running out of disk space.

The only solution to this problem i am aware of is to unarchive them one by one, keeping track of the disk space. Then move around some to another filesystem temporarily to make space for a new one or similar approaches needed also.

At first, list the contents of the archive, assuming the `tar` file is `foobar.tar`:

```
tar -tvf foobar.tar
```

Then start unarchiving one by one e.g.:

```
tar -xvf foobar.tar file1_to_unarchive
tar -xvf foobar.tar file2_to_unarchive
```

and so on. Like i said, keep track of the disk space and move around file(s) when needed.

Comment: you  are telling that move around another filesystem ....i don't understad that ....

Comment: drive or file system??

Comment: @SudipDas another partition if you will (temporarily).